# LWC not showing when calling inside VF Page Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have a component which suddenly stopped working for the last 2 days.
I have an LWC component which I am using inside VF Page
Below is the structure

1. priceConfiguration VF Page

```
<apex:page id="PriceConfiguration" standardController="Product2" lightningStylesheets="true">
  <style type="text/css">
    .slds-form-element__icon {
      display: none !important;
    }
  </style>
  <apex:includeLightning />
  <div id="priceConfiguration"></div>
  <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:priceConfigurationApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:priceConfigurationComponent",
        { recordId: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" },
        "priceConfiguration"
      );
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

2. priceConfigurationApp

```
<aura:application description="Price Configuration Application" 
    access="global" 
    extends="ltng:outApp" 
    implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="string" />
    <c:priceConfigurationComponent recordId="{!v.recordId}" />
</aura:application>
```

3. priceConfigurationComponent

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="string" />
  <lightning:navigation aura:id="navigation" />
  <aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container { min-width: 70vw; }
  </aura:html> 
  <c:priceConfiguration recordId="{!v.recordId}" onclose="{!c.handleClose}"></c:priceConfiguration>
</aura:component>
```

4. priceConfiguration is LWC Component, this component is working great if I directly run it in Lightning, but it shows empty page while I run `priceConfiguration VF Page` with this error (screenshot)

It works fine when I call different LWC in my aura component, not sure what went wrong?
Is something new update from Salesforce breaking stuff?

This is working fine in all the sandboxes only not working in Production.
Let me know if you additional information

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While there might be more errors than this within the `priceConfiguration` component, the `lightning:navigation` component is not supported in VisualForce pages.

Here:

> Descriptor Lightning:navigation |  Targets
> Lightning Experience, Experience Builder Sites, Salesforce Mobile App

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation)

The only solution for this is to not use `lightning:navigation` in your `priceConfigurationComponent` component.

Comment: Still the same issue. and forgot to mention, This is working completely fine in Sandboxes, only Production is giving trouble

Comment: Hmm. It actually shouldn't be working at all. Does navigation work in your sandbox? Also, can you try ONLY the `priceConfiguration` component directly hosted inside the `ltng:outApp` app? That way you can eliminate any other possible sources of errors.

Comment: Yes, navigation works in the sandbox, I am using it to redirect back to the record detail page. answer to your 2nd question, I tried `priceConfiguration` directly inside the aura app and it's not working, the same result.

Comment: I think I got the issue, we recently enabled LWS in our org and after that, it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

LWS and Message Service do works fine in Lightning Experience but not in Classic. Changing to pubsub model works perfectly.